# In JS, experienced a logical error when choosing the time zone for the event from the location's time zone (time)

Tags: javascript, html

Based on the user's requirements, I'm creating an event-driven timer that counts down dynamically. The user can choose the time, date, backdrop image or video for the countdown, the venue for the event, the venue for the event's planning, and the message that will be displayed after the countdown is over.
The countdown is determined by the viewer's location or timestamps. Upon the conclusion of the countdown, a popup message appears.
However, I encountered a problem when selecting the event timestamp from the current date to the event date.

(the countdown time to the time zone specified from a dropdown List)

According to the time zones Pacific Time, Mountain Time, Central Time, Eastern Time, Indiana (East), Atlantic Time (Canada), etc., the incident in this scenario occurred in Chicago, Korea, Thailand, etc., after 7,15,250 days. The user is currently located in Japan, Australia, India, etc., thus their current time zone is not in agreement with the location of the event.

Please assist in converting the time zone from the provided dropdown list.

```js
document.getElementById("date_time_show").innerHTML = date_time_show();

function date_time_show() {
  var x = document.getElementById("date_ab").value;
  // document.getElementById("date_time_show").innerHTML = x;
  var xy = document.getElementById("time_ab").value;
  // document.getElementById("date_time_show").innerHTML = xy;
  document.getElementById("date_time_show").innerHTML = x + ' ' + xy;
}



function myFunction() {
  var countDownDate_ab = document.getElementById('date_ab');
  var countDowntime_ab = document.getElementById('time_ab');

  var xy = countDownDate_ab.value + ' ' + countDowntime_ab.value;
  var currentVal = new Date(xy).getTime();

  // Update the count down every 1 second
  var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get today's date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now and the count down date
    var distance = currentVal - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Output the result in an element with id="Countdown_showing"
    document.getElementById("Countdown_showing").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " +
      minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
      clearInterval(x);
      // document.getElementById("Countdown_showing").innerHTML = "Chal ab nikal!";  <-- Pause it for movement
      document.getElementById('Countdown_showing').innerHTML = document.getElementById('message').value;
    }
  }, 1000);
}

//disable previous dates in date picker using JQ and JS
var today = new Date();
var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
// $('#setTodaysDate').attr('min',today);
document.getElementById('date_ab').setAttribute('min', today);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>


  <style>
    p {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 60px;
      margin-top: 0px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <label for="countdown">Countdown :</label>
  <!-- <input type="datetime-local" id="countdown1" name="countdown"  > -->
  <div>


    <!-- <input type="date" id="setTodaysDate" name="setTodaysDate">  <br> -->
    <input type="date" id="date_ab" name="countdown">
    <input type="time" id="time_ab" name="countdown">
    <input type="text" id="message" name="message">
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction(), date_time_show() , submitDate()"> Submit </button>

    <!-- <select class="dropdownTimeZone" id="dropdownTimeZone" onChange="submitDate()"></select> -->


    <select class="form-control" name="timezone">
      <option value="">Use Device Timezone </option>
      <option value="Pacific/Midway">(GMT-11:00) Midway Island </option>
      <option value="US/Samoa">(GMT-11:00) Samoa </option>
      <option value="US/Hawaii">(GMT-10:00) Hawaii </option>
      <option value="US/Alaska">(GMT-08:00) Alaska </option>
      <option value="US/Pacific">(GMT-07:00) Pacific Time (US &amp;amp; Canada) </option>
      <option value="America/Tijuana">(GMT-07:00) Tijuana </option>
      <option value="US/Arizona">(GMT-07:00) Arizona </option>
      <option value="US/Mountain">(GMT-06:00) Mountain Time (US &amp;amp; Canada) </option>
      <option value="America/Chihuahua">(GMT-06:00) Chihuahua </option>
      <option value="America/Mazatlan">(GMT-06:00) Mazatlan </option>
      <option value="America/Mexico_City">(GMT-05:00) Mexico City </option>
      <option value="America/Monterrey">(GMT-05:00) Monterrey </option>
      <option value="Canada/Saskatchewan">(GMT-06:00) Saskatchewan </option>
      <option value="US/Central">(GMT-05:00) Central Time (US &amp;amp; Canada) </option>
      <option value="US/Eastern">(GMT-04:00) Eastern Time (US &amp;amp; Canada) </option>
      <option value="US/East-Indiana">(GMT-04:00) Indiana (East) </option>
      <option value="America/Bogota">(GMT-05:00) Bogota </option>
      <option value="America/Lima">(GMT-05:00) Lima </option>
      <option value="America/Caracas">(GMT-04:00) Caracas </option>
      <option value="Canada/Atlantic">(GMT-03:00) Atlantic Time (Canada) </option>
      <option value="America/La_Paz">(GMT-04:00) La Paz </option>
      <option value="America/Santiago">(GMT-04:00) Santiago </option>
      <option value="Canada/Newfoundland">(GMT-02:30) Newfoundland </option>
      <option value="America/Buenos_Aires">(GMT-03:00) Buenos Aires </option>
      <option value="Atlantic/Stanley">(GMT-03:00) Stanley </option>
      <option value="Atlantic/Azores">(GMT-00:00) Azores </option>
      <option value="Atlantic/Cape_Verde">(GMT-01:00) Cape Verde Is. </option>
      <option value="Africa/Casablanca">(GMT+01:00) Casablanca </option>
      <option value="Europe/Dublin">(GMT+01:00) Dublin </option>
      <option value="Europe/Lisbon">(GMT+01:00) Lisbon </option>
      <option value="Europe/London">(GMT+01:00) London </option>
      <option value="Africa/Monrovia">(GMT-00:00) Monrovia </option>
      <option value="Europe/Amsterdam">(GMT+02:00) Amsterdam </option>
      <option value="Europe/Belgrade">(GMT+02:00) Belgrade </option>
      <option value="Europe/Berlin">(GMT+02:00) Berlin </option>
      <option value="Europe/Bratislava">(GMT+02:00) Bratislava </option>
      <option value="Europe/Brussels">(GMT+02:00) Brussels </option>
      <option value="Europe/Budapest">(GMT+02:00) Budapest </option>
      <option value="Europe/Copenhagen">(GMT+02:00) Copenhagen </option>
      <option value="Europe/Ljubljana">(GMT+02:00) Ljubljana </option>
      <option value="Europe/Madrid">(GMT+02:00) Madrid </option>
      <option value="Europe/Paris">(GMT+02:00) Paris </option>
      <option value="Europe/Prague">(GMT+02:00) Prague </option>
      <option value="Europe/Rome">(GMT+02:00) Rome </option>
      <option value="Europe/Sarajevo">(GMT+02:00) Sarajevo </option>
      <option value="Europe/Skopje">(GMT+02:00) Skopje </option>
      <option value="Europe/Stockholm">(GMT+02:00) Stockholm </option>
      <option value="Europe/Vienna">(GMT+02:00) Vienna </option>
      <option value="Europe/Warsaw">(GMT+02:00) Warsaw </option>
      <option value="Europe/Zagreb">(GMT+02:00) Zagreb </option>
      <option value="Europe/Athens">(GMT+03:00) Athens </option>
      <option value="Europe/Bucharest">(GMT+03:00) Bucharest </option>
      <option value="Africa/Cairo">(GMT+02:00) Cairo </option>
      <option value="Africa/Harare">(GMT+02:00) Harare </option>
      <option value="Europe/Helsinki">(GMT+03:00) Helsinki </option>
      <option value="Europe/Istanbul">(GMT+03:00) Istanbul </option>
      <option value="Asia/Jerusalem">(GMT+03:00) Jerusalem </option>
      <option value="Europe/Kiev">(GMT+03:00) Kyiv </option>
      <option value="Europe/Minsk">(GMT+03:00) Minsk </option>
      <option value="Europe/Riga">(GMT+03:00) Riga </option>
      <option value="Europe/Sofia">(GMT+03:00) Sofia </option>
      <option value="Europe/Tallinn">(GMT+03:00) Tallinn </option>
      <option value="Europe/Vilnius">(GMT+03:00) Vilnius </option>
      <option value="Asia/Baghdad">(GMT+03:00) Baghdad </option>
      <option value="Asia/Kuwait">(GMT+03:00) Kuwait </option>
      <option value="Africa/Nairobi">(GMT+03:00) Nairobi </option>
      <option value="Asia/Riyadh">(GMT+03:00) Riyadh </option>
      <option value="Europe/Moscow">(GMT+03:00) Moscow </option>
      <option value="Asia/Tehran">(GMT+04:30) Tehran </option>
      <option value="Asia/Baku">(GMT+04:00) Baku </option>
      <option value="Europe/Volgograd">(GMT+04:00) Volgograd </option>
      <option value="Asia/Muscat">(GMT+04:00) Muscat </option>
      <option value="Asia/Tbilisi">(GMT+04:00) Tbilisi </option>
      <option value="Asia/Yerevan">(GMT+04:00) Yerevan </option>
      <option value="Asia/Kabul">(GMT+04:30) Kabul </option>
      <option value="Asia/Karachi">(GMT+05:00) Karachi </option>
      <option value="Asia/Tashkent">(GMT+05:00) Tashkent </option>
      <option value="Asia/Kolkata">(GMT+05:30) Kolkata </option>
      <option value="Asia/Kathmandu">(GMT+05:45) Kathmandu </option>
      <option value="Asia/Yekaterinburg">(GMT+05:00) Ekaterinburg </option>
      <option value="Asia/Almaty">(GMT+06:00) Almaty </option>
      <option value="Asia/Dhaka">(GMT+06:00) Dhaka </option>
      <option value="Asia/Novosibirsk">(GMT+07:00) Novosibirsk </option>
      <option value="Asia/Bangkok">(GMT+07:00) Bangkok </option>
      <option value="Asia/Jakarta">(GMT+07:00) Jakarta </option>
      <option value="Asia/Krasnoyarsk">(GMT+07:00) Krasnoyarsk </option>
      <option value="Asia/Chongqing">(GMT+08:00) Chongqing </option>
      <option value="Asia/Hong_Kong">(GMT+08:00) Hong Kong </option>
      <option value="Asia/Kuala_Lumpur">(GMT+08:00) Kuala Lumpur </option>
      <option value="Australia/Perth">(GMT+08:00) Perth </option>
      <option value="Asia/Singapore">(GMT+08:00) Singapore </option>
      <option value="Asia/Taipei">(GMT+08:00) Taipei </option>
      <option value="Asia/Ulaanbaatar">(GMT+08:00) Ulaan Bataar </option>
      <option value="Asia/Urumqi">(GMT+06:00) Urumqi </option>
      <option value="Asia/Irkutsk">(GMT+08:00) Irkutsk </option>
      <option value="Asia/Seoul">(GMT+09:00) Seoul </option>
      <option value="Asia/Tokyo">(GMT+09:00) Tokyo </option>
      <option value="Australia/Adelaide">(GMT+09:30) Adelaide </option>
      <option value="Australia/Darwin">(GMT+09:30) Darwin </option>
      <option value="Asia/Yakutsk">(GMT+09:00) Yakutsk </option>
      <option value="Australia/Brisbane">(GMT+10:00) Brisbane </option>
      <option value="Australia/Canberra">(GMT+10:00) Canberra </option>
      <option value="Pacific/Guam">(GMT+10:00) Guam </option>
      <option value="Australia/Hobart">(GMT+10:00) Hobart </option>
      <option value="Australia/Melbourne">(GMT+10:00) Melbourne </option>
      <option value="Pacific/Port_Moresby">(GMT+10:00) Port Moresby </option>
      <option value="Australia/Sydney">(GMT+10:00) Sydney </option>
      <option value="Asia/Vladivostok">(GMT+10:00) Vladivostok </option>
      <option value="Asia/Magadan">(GMT+11:00) Magadan </option>
      <option value="Pacific/Auckland">(GMT+12:00) Auckland </option>
      <option value="Pacific/Fiji">(GMT+12:00) Fiji </option>
    </select>

    <p>
      <h4> Current Date Time Showing : <span id="date_time_show"></span></h4>
    </p>
    <p>
      <h4> Selected Timezone Showing : <span id="stimezone"></span></h4>
    </p>
  </div>

  <p id="Countdown_print">Countdown Started : </p>
  <p id="Countdown_showing"></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Let's say it's 12PM and I live in zulu (GMT), I set the countdown clock for the same day at 2PM. When I set the time zone for GMT+2 what is expected? Is the second clock countdown to 4PM instead of 2PM? So the second countdown clock would actually run for 4 hours and the first clock runs for 2 hours? Or there's an offset to the second time wherein both countdown clocks run for 2 hours? I'm not sure how a countdown clock would serve any purpose across time zones.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is the way you try to get the current Timestamp.
You can get the current Timestamp by using the static Method of `Date` by using `Date.now()`.

The rest works fine, although there are some operations that can be optimized, but as this seems one of your first programming projects, i wouldn't get into much details for now.

```js
    // Get today's date and time
    var now = Date.now();
```

Comment: I appreciate your response.

I wish to emphasise that I make countdown timers based on time zones, just like events that are scheduled for this day and that hour in this nation's time zone. However, I prefer that the countdown be generated according to the time zone I choose rather than my actual time. I was told that the countdown had already finished if I selected "US/Mountain" (GMT-06:00) Mountain Time (US & Canada) from the drop-down option.

Comment: However, I encountered a problem when selecting the event timestamp from the current date to the event date.

According to the time zones Pacific Time, Mountain Time, Central Time, Eastern Time, Indiana (East), Atlantic Time (Canada), etc., the incident in this scenario occurred in Chicago, Korea, Thailand, etc., after 7,15,250 days. The user is currently located in Japan, Australia, India, etc., thus their current time zone is not in agreement with the location of the event.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not claiming that this is a superior strategy. I want to know whether there is a better way to achieve the user-based generate countdown.

```js
// Detect user representative location if available
let repLoc = (typeof Intl == 'object' &&
    typeof Intl.DateTimeFormat == 'function' &&
    typeof Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions == 'function') ?
  Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone : 'default';

function setRepLoc(evt) {
  showSampleDates(this.value);
}

function showSampleDates(repLoc) {
  let el0 = document.getElementById('sDate0');
  let el1 = document.getElementById('sOff0');
  let el2 = document.getElementById('sDate1');
  let el3 = document.getElementById('sOff1');


  let d0 = new Date(Date.now());
  let d1 = new Date(Date.UTC(2022, 8, 1, 3));


  let opts = {
    weekday: 'short',
    day: 'numeric',
    month: 'short',
    year: 'numeric',
    hour: 'numeric',
    minute: '2-digit',
    timeZone: repLoc,
    timeZoneName: 'long'
  };
  let offOpts = {
    hour: 'numeric',
    hour12: false,
    timeZone: repLoc,
    timeZoneName: 'short'
  }
  if (repLoc == 'default') {
    el0.textContent = '';
    el1.textContent = '';
    el2.textContent = '';
    el3.textContent = '';
  } else {
    el0.textContent = d0.toLocaleString('en-NZ', opts);
    el1.textContent = d0.toLocaleString('en-NZ', offOpts).split(' ')[1];
    el2.textContent = d1.toLocaleString('en-NZ', opts);
    el3.textContent = d1.toLocaleString('en-NZ', offOpts).split(' ')[1];
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  let sel = document.getElementById('repLoc')
  if (repLoc) {
    sel.options[0].text = repLoc;
    sel.options[0].value = repLoc;
    sel.selectedIndex = 0;
    setRepLoc.call(sel);
  }
  sel.addEventListener(
    'change',
    setRepLoc,
    false);
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>


  <style>
    p {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 60px;
      margin-top: 0px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>IANA loc:
        <td>
          <select id="repLoc">
            <option selected value="default">Select a location
              <option>Europe/Amsterdam
                <option>Europe/Andorra
                  <option>Europe/Astrakhan
                    <option>Europe/Athens
                      <option>Europe/Belfast
                        <option>Pacific/Samoa
                          <option>Pacific/Kiritimati
                            <option>Antarctica/DumontDUrville
                              <option>Antarctica/Davis
                                <option>America/Chicago
                                  <option>Australia/Brisbane
          </select>
          <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
          <div></div>

          <tr>
            <td>Sample:
              <td id="sDate0">
                <tr>
                  <td>Offset:
                    <td id="sOff0">
                      <tr>
                        <td>Sample:
                          <td id="sDate1">
                            <tr>
                              <td>Offset:
                                <td id="sOff1">

  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please explain why this is a better approache

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I'm not claiming that this is a superior strategy. I want to know whether there is a better way to achieve the user-based generate countdown.